# SearchView memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am getting a memory leak from SearchView menu item

this is my code

```
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        if (hasSearchOption()) {
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            if (item == null) {
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
                // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
                SearchManager searchManager =
                        (SearchManager) Controller.getContext().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
                SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
                ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class);
                searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                        searchManager.getSearchableInfo(cn));
                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                         //DO STUFF
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Class Name

```
         | Ref. Objects | Shallow Heap | Ref. Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mOnQueryChangeListener com.test.fragments.TestFragmentImpl$1 @ 0xa58ff9c0|            1 |           16 |                16 |            16
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

if i comment out setting the setOnQueryTextListener the leak disappears. I don't understand this leak cause the body of the search is empty so how is it leaking?

Answer (score 2):

From your fragment, save a reference to your searchItem MenuItem from your onCreateOptionsMenu and then simply override onDestroyOptionsMenu() and call searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(null) like so:

```
// Set this in your onCreateOptionsMenu method

private MenuItem searchItem; 


@Override
public void onDestroyOptionsMenu()
{
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(null);
    searchItem = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This only fixed the issue in the simulator running SDK 33** The problem still persisted on a real device running SDK 29.

I had this problem because my searchView was inside a fragment. I found the answer [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36940397), specifically comment #6.

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    // make sure to set this null BEFORE you set the _binding to null
    binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(null) // <--- Fixes the leak on the simulator running SDK 33

    _binding = null
}
```

I just noticed @MichaelKrause said the same thing but the difference between his answer and mine's is that `searchItem` isn't a property that I can use because I use `viewBinding`.